# Symfony secured pages

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have login page with login form. So if user is already logged I want redirect him from login page to another. Secured area is all pages with `.*/secured.html` and login page url is - `login/page.html`. When I am trying to `$this->container->get('security.context');` I got error that there is no  security token because current page is not under secured area. So If I want to use token (if exists) **should I add all these pages to the secured area?** In this way symfony2 will check every time if user is logged (and maybe will redirect to login page) but If I add

```
    login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false
```

auth token also will not exist.

So what is the way to use auth token at all application pages? Or all these pages should be added to secured area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn off the security you don't have a token. Your login page have to place behind the firewall. And no you don't have to
add all your single pages to your settings.

Here is an example:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: /account/login
                check_path: /account/login_check
            logout:
                path: /account/logout
            anonymous: true
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

access_control:
        - { path: ^/account/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/movie/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

As you can see I activated the security on all pages, but I'll allow to access anonymously. 
With this access control: `- { path: ^/movie/, role: ROLE_USER }` I've full control which user can access the page,
which implies that the user is already logged in.

For a deeper look I can recommend the Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> So If I want to use token (if exists) should I add all these pages to
>   the secured area?

Yes, you have to put those where you want to access security token behind firewall. If you want to also access security token in login page, you also have to put it in behind the same firewall. But then make the access control for it as `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secured/login/page.html$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```